# Non-contact voltage tester beeping near anything metal in my house?

Tags: grounding, multimeter, induction, earth, leakage-current

Ok this is my first post so apologies if this is inappropriate but I need some solid opinions from guys who know about house earthing

So me and my dad just moved into an old house and I was walking around with my multimeter in NCV setting and it starts beeping when I hold the meter up in the air.

Now I'm not talking a stray beep every now and then like a false reading, this thing beeps continuously until I bring it back down close to my body and immediately beeps again when I raise it up, I'm familiar with inductance and body capacitance and all that but this is spooky

- It beeps when I put it close to the kitchen bench (which has a metal strip along the perimeter), as soon as I touch the metal it stops beeping
- It beeps near his ACOUSTIC guitar strings which is sitting on a stand and stops once I touch the strings
- It beeps near any metal plate such as a small metal poster or piece of metal rod I have laying around and again, stops once I touch them
- It beeps near some of the door hinges too

Is my house not grounded properly or something because both our phones act weird and slow in the kitchen and in some spots around the house

Now I'm an electrical engineer so please don't tell me I'm using my meter wrong or that it's broken because it beeps everywhere it's supposed to (near mains plugs, lights, appliances) but I've never seen the NCV go this crazy around random things and I'm worried the house may need some attention

Thank you to anyone who reads this and chips in, all advice is appreciated.

Comment: If you're an EE then check the earth impedance. If you're an EE then any doubt about safety should have you calling an electrician if you can't do this test yourself. So, I'm questioning your thought process here rather than telling you the use your meter correctly. There is a difference.

Comment: If we are not allowed to tell you you’re using your meter wrong or your meter is broken, maybe you could make it clear  what we ARE allowed to tell you?

Comment: As an EE you should know that the amount of **current** is what matters. So how much **AC current** is flowing between a proper ground (stick a metal pin in the earth for that) and the guitar etc.? My guess is that your NCV meter is simply too sensitive. If you doubt the electrical system and you can't check it yourself (being an EE doesn't mean you're educated to handle house installations) then hire a certified electrician.

Comment: I'm an electrical engineer in training not a qualified electrician, meaning I know enough to know this isn't right, it's also midnight so calling an electrician isn't an option.

Comment: Well, if you are in training, how do you respond when you are told that what you are doing might be wrong? Do you start every tutorial or lesson that you attend by telling the lecturer or trainer that you might be a tad sensitive to criticism?

Comment: Everyone is in training, we all have our areas of expertise and electrician work isn't mine. Forgot how rude you lot can be, I'm asking if my house has an earth leak.

Comment: Bimplerekkie is the only one here that's added something useful. My area is microcontrollers not house wiring.

Comment: I don't think the meter is too sensitive because it has to be pretty close to mains plugs to beep, but in some spots I hold the meter in the air and it beeps until I lower it and then again once I raise it. I'm not worried that the house will burn down or electrocute me it's just interfering with our phones and I'm wondering if it is an earth leak, but what would cause the airborne readings?

Comment: Is your house very close to a radio station tower, or overhead/underground power lines?  Something is emitting enough RF or volts/meter to be detectable. Or your meter is too sensitive. I'm not convinced a home grounding issue is the culprit here.

Comment: I suggest that you try again in daylight when you can safely switch off the electricity to the house and report back.

Comment: Work through this methodically. Do an A/B test by turning off the whole-house breaker. If that stops it, work your way through the branch circuits. If the phenomenon continues with whole-house power off, turn the power back on, get a scope and clip a length of wire to the probe. What frequency is the noise?  A high-power AM broadcast station, a next door ham with a 1KW amplifier, other RF emitters are indeed possible causes and will easily be differentiated from 60 Hz powerline fields.

Comment: Multimeter NCV sensors are often capacitive rather than inductive; this is what you have.  If your meter is not too sensitive, then I agree with @rdtsc that there may be an outside field generator nearby.  It could be something like a neighbor with an "invisible fence".  Lucky you're an EE!  Grab a scope if you have one, plug it into the wall to ground it, and probe one of your "phantom" sources (don't use the probe ground).  Post a picture of the signal.  Then we can all guess where it comes from.

Comment: Thank you for your time lads, I quickly checked the AC voltage from mains earth to my bench before I left for work and it gave me 7 volts AC, not sure if that's negligible or not. I'm not near a power station but there's a decent sized transformer out front of my next door neighbors house up on the power lines, but the UHF/VHF idea could be promising, unfortunately I don't have a digital field strength meter, would a simple radio be of any use to help detect whoever is making all this noise?

Comment: That may  happen if phase and neutral not running in same conduit or cable. Especially if the load consumesh big current. Somebody may tried to fix broken wire and jumped only one wire from another circuit.

Answer (score 2):

It's probable that the 'non-contact voltage tester' is responding to a strong RF field, with the metal objects acting as 'retro reflectors'.

The sizes of those objects point to a VHF / UHF transmitter nearby.

It would most certainly not be a grounding issue since the metal beading of a bench, guitar strings, a metal rod and a metal hinge would not be even remotely connected to anything electrical.

The presence of a strong RF field, and its frequency, may be confirmed using a digital field strength meter.